# GetCPInfoEx undocumented behavior/errors

Tags: winapi, windows-7, codepages

GetCPInfoEx fails with codepage 20949 and 1147.

For 20949, the error in GetLastError is "The specified resource name cannot be found in the image file"

For 1147, GetLastError is empty.

Both these code pages should be valid according to [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd317756%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), are installed on my system, and the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318081%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) doesn't say anything about GetLastError being empty.

Is there something special about these code pages? Missing something in the documentation?